# Eshell - is there something like open-eshell-here?

Tags: emacs, dired, eshell

In the Windows Explorer there is a function 'command-prompt-here' that opens a command prompt for the actual directory.

Is there something similar for eshell, that enables me to open an eshell from dired in the actual directory? When I look at a file, can I open an eshell for the directory that holds that file? Would it be possible to reuse an already open eshell, that is, show that eshell with a new prompt that reflects the actual directory, instead of opening a new instance?

Would be nice to avoid all those 'cd ../../../dir1/dir2'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can easily create such a thing:

```
(defun my-eshell ()
  (interactive)
  (eshell "new")) ; "new" ensures that a new eshell is created
```

And call `my-eshell` instead of `eshell`. A disadvantage of the above is that it always opens a new `eshell` even if there is already some opened with the correct directory.

Comment: I was a bit sceptical at first, but it works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The following also works:

```
C-u M-x eshell
```